# Explain why J is a prime Ideal in Z[x]

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am trying to prove that the ideal $J=<x+1>$ is prime in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. I know that if the generator is prime, then the ring modulo the generator is an integral domain. I can show that this is true in this case after a bit of work. However, I was wondering if there was a quicker way to do this. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: It's the kernel of the map to $\Bbb Z$ which takes $x$ to $-1$.

Comment: We can of course *directly* prove that domain $R\,\Rightarrow\, x\!-\!a\,$ prime in $\,R[x]\,$ via the remainder theorem: 

$$x\!-\!a\mid fg\iff \underbrace{ f(a)g(a)=0\iff f(a)=0\ \ {\rm or}\ \ g(a)=0}_{\large R\ \text{a domain}}\iff x\!-\!a\mid f\ \ {\rm or}\ \ x\!-\!a\mid g$$